# on click trigger phone call in html

Tags: html

On the phone number click I want to trigger the call thing in my site.

This is how I am showing the number.

```
<li><i class="fa fa-phone pr-5 pl-10"></i>+12 123 123 123</li>
```

How do I add the `tell` thing here.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make the number a link and in the href attribute put "tel:younumberhere"

As per http://thenewcode.com/536/Adding-Phone-Numbers-To-Web-Pages-With-HTML5-and-Microdata

Answer (score 1):

Create a link like this:

```
<li><i class="fa fa-phone pr-5 pl-10"></i><a href="tel:+12123123123">+12 123 123 123</a></li>
```

On Android it will bring up the Phone app and pre-enter the digits for 2125551212 without auto dialing.